# cant login after successfully register to database

Tags: php, authentication, login-script

This is my login code, cant figure out whats wrong ( the last if, always goes to the last else ). i tried everything but still no luck.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();

if($_POST['submit']){
    include_once("connection.php");
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if($query){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $userId = $row[0];
        $dbUsername = $row[1];
        $dbPassword = $row[3];
    }

    if ($username = $dbUsername && $password == $dbPassword) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $userId;
        header('Location: users.php');
    }else {
        header('Location: error.php');
    }
}
?>
```

and thas my connection code

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db('login');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: You're using `mysql_connect` but not `mysql` functions. Please review the manual on `mysqli_*`. I'd also recommend in not using plain text passwords and highly recommend the use of prepared statements.

Comment: change $dbPassword = $row[3]; to $dbPassword = $row[2];

Comment: i'd go with Daryl Gills Hint - you can't mix "mysql_connect" (which is depreceated by the way) and "mysqli"

Comment: I highly suggest you read up on [pdo_mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) before your code stops functioning completely. MySql has been deprecated for eons and will completely disappear with PHP v.7

Answer (score 2):

You are going to kick yourself... you have only a single `=` in your `if`.

```
if ($username = $dbUsername && $password == $dbPassword) {
```

Should be

```
if ($username == $dbUsername && $password == $dbPassword) {
```

The single `=` turns it into an assignment instead of a comparison.

Beyond that you are actually doing the comparison twice; once in SQL to get back the username and password, the second time in PHP. If your query returns the user id, you already know that the username/password did the trick.

You are also mixing `mysql_connect` and `mysqli_query` (and `mysql_fetch_row`). As the others have suggested, you need to move to the `mysqli` class or to `PDO`. But to get you going, you need to at very least change `mysqli_query` to `mysql_query` and `mysqli_fetch_row` to `mysql_fetch_row`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_query($connection, $sql)` instead of `mysqli_query($connection, $sql);`
as you are using `mysql_connect`